# Use Unicode characters in Indy TIdHTTPServer AuthRealm

Tags: delphi, pascal, indy

How can I use Unicode characters in the `TIdHTTPResponseInfo.AuthRealm` property in the `TIdHTTPServer.OnCommandGet` event handler?

```
procedure TMainForm.HttpServerCommandGet(Context: TIdContext; RequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; ResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
resourcestring
  DefaultPage =
  '<!DOCTYPE html>'                                               + sLineBreak +
  '<title>Embedded Web Server</title>'                            + sLineBreak +
  '<h1>Embedded Web Server</h1>'                                  + sLineBreak +
  '<p>Приветствие!'                                               + sLineBreak +
  '<br>Это веб-страница, которая отображается по умолчанию.</p>'  ;
begin
  if UserHandle = IdUserHandleNone then
    if not RequestInfo.AuthExists or (UserManager.AuthenticateUser(RequestInfo.AuthUsername, RequestInfo.AuthPassword, UserHandle) < 0) then
      begin
        ResponseInfo.AuthRealm := 'Аутентификация пользователя';
        ResponseInfo.ContentText := 'Несанкционированный доступ запрещен!';
        ResponseInfo.ContentType := 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
        Exit
      end;
  if RequestInfo.Document = '/' then
    begin
      ResponseInfo.ContentText := DefaultPage;
      ResponseInfo.ContentType := 'text/html; charset=utf-8'
    end
end;
```

[image]

---

Okay, I wrote the event handler for TIdHTTPResponseInfo.OnConnect with follows code:

```
procedure TMainForm.HttpServerConnect(Context: TIdContext);
begin
  Context.Connection.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8
end;
```

Unfortunately, it did not provide the required text handling at response headers.

[image]

Comment: You mean "International", correct?

Comment: No. I mean NATIONAL (Russian, Polish, German etc). The INTERNATIONAL (En, En-Us) is displayed valid (by default).

Answer (score 3):

At this time, `TIdHTTPServer` does not *natively* support non-ASCII characters in HTTP headers, and that is especially true for the `realm` parameter of the `WWW-Authenticate` header, per the definition of `quoted-string` of RFC 2616 that is used in RFC 2617 <sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1: Indy does not implement RFCs 7230..7235 or 7617 in either `TIdHTTP` or `TIdHTTPServer` at this time.</sup>

That being said, when Indy writes and reads strings, it uses the `IOHandler`'s default string encoding (unless specified differently by the caller), which is `IndyTextEncoding_ASCII` by default. In the server's `OnConnect` event, you can set the `AContext.Connection.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding` property to `IndyTextEncoding_UTF8` instead, and then `TIdHTTPServer` will write and read HTTP headers as UTF-8 instead of ASCII.

Although RFCs 7235 and 7617 do not formally allow UTF-8 in the `realm`, they do use the definition of `quoted-string` from RFC 7230, which allows for octets up to 0xFF (the RFC 2616 definition does not), which makes me think that UTF-8 *can* be used. And many (but not all!) web browsers do support UTF-8 in the `realm`.  But, for the widest possible compatibility, you should stick to using only ASCII characters in the `realm`, until IETF formally defines that UTF-8 is allowed to be used and all web browsers implement it.

Comment: I found the article in Internet (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/WWW-Authenticate) with example where UTF-8 encoding is pointed exactly in WWW-Authenticate HTTP response header
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Access to the staging site", charset="UTF-8"

Comment: The `charset` parameter only applies to the encoding of the user credentials (before they are base64 encoded for transmission), not to the `realm` parameter. The Mozilla page you linked to even says as much: "*Tells the client the server's prefered encoding scheme **when submiting a username and password**. The only allowed value is the case insensitive string "UTF-8". **This does not relate to the encoding of the realm string**.*"