# Indy Http Server delivers Javascript with Syntax errors

Tags: delphi, indy

I am trying to use Indy to serve Javascript (deploying a Swagger UI to render API documentation).

```
procedure TfmMain.SendJavaScriptFileResponse(AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo; AFileName: String);
begin
  AResponseInfo.ContentType := 'application/javascript';
  AResponseInfo.CharSet := 'utf-8';
  var LFileContents := TStringList.Create;
  try
    LFileContents.LoadFromFile(AFileName);
    AResponseInfo.ContentText := LFileContents.Text;
  finally
    LFileContents.Free;
  end;
end;
```

When the browser receives the Javascript and attempts to run it, I get a syntax error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: illegal character U+20AC

The respoinsde headers received from the Indy IdHttpServer look like so:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Content-Encoding: utf-8
Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1063786
Date: Sun, 05 Feb 2023 20:45:56 GMT
```

However, when I serve the exact same Javascript files via my hosted website, the Javascript runs fine in the browser with no errors.

Is there a setting or character set I need to use when sending Javascript files using the Indy HTTP server?

Comment: Q: What happens if you remove the Euro symbol (Unicode U+20AC) from your JS source?  See this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54911343/421195

Comment: How are you serving the Javascript, exactly? Please show your actual code. There are several different ways to serve content in `TIdHTTPServer`. I'm guessing that you are using `AResponseInfo.ContentText` without specifying an encoding, rather than using `AResponseInfo.ContentStream` or `AResponseInfo.(Smart)ServeFile()`, is that right?

Comment: @paulsm4 that post deals with HTTP headers, but Javascript is sent in the HTTP body instead. So that post doesn't apply here.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: clearly the problem is "encoding".  The OP is using IndyHTTP; and his JS text has at least one Unicode character (U+20AC).  Q: What are his alternatives?  PS: It's been at least 5 years since I've used Delphi or played with Indy myself - I'm sure "Things have Changed" since then :)

Comment: @Tav: are you saving your JS text as 8-bit ASCII (or 8-bit UTF-8)?  For troubleshooting purposes, does "everything work" if you don't include the Euro chararacter in your JS code?

Comment: @paulsm4 yes, this is clearly an encoding issue, but the way TIdHTTPServer sends headers is very different than how it sends the body. Nothing has changed in recent years in regards to that. I've already mentioned the different ways the body can be sent. Only one (the `ContentText`) is subject to encoding issues on the server side, though all of them can send/omit a charset header that messes up the client if it not set to the correct value for the type of data being sent. Which is why I asked the OP *how* the JS data is being sent

Comment: Have update question with code used to send file contents. I do set the charset on the response info. I also tried utf-16 but that didn't work either.

Comment: @Tav "*I do set the charset on the response info*" - but you are not specifying the encoding when loading the file into a `string` to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading the Javascript from a file into a `string`, and then you are sending that `string` to the client.  That requires 2 data conversions at runtime - from the file's encoding to UTF-16 in memory, and from UTF-16 to the specified `AResponseInfo.Charset` on the data transmission to the client.  Either one of those conversions can fail if you are not careful.

In memory, a `string` in Delphi 2009+ is always UTF-16 encoded, but you are not specifying the file's encoding when loading the file into the `TStringList`.  So, if the file uses an encoding other than ASCII (say, UTF-8), does not have a BOM, and contains any non-ASCII characters (say, the Euro sign `€`), then `TStringList` WILL NOT decode the file into UTF-16 correctly.  In which case, you MUST specify the file's actual encoding, eg:

```
procedure TfmMain.SendJavaScriptFileResponse(
  AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo;
  const AFileName: String);
begin
  AResponseInfo.ContentType := 'application/javascript';
  AResponseInfo.CharSet := 'utf-8';
  var LFileContents := TStringList.Create;
  try
    LFileContents.LoadFromFile(AFileName, TEncoding.UTF8); // <-- HERE
    AResponseInfo.ContentText := LFileContents.Text;
  finally
    LFileContents.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Another option is to send the actual file itself, without having to load and decode it into memory first, eg:

```
procedure TfmMain.SendJavaScriptFileResponse(
  AContext: TIdContext;
  AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo;
  const AFileName: String);
begin
  AResponseInfo.ContentType := 'application/javascript';
  AResponseInfo.CharSet := 'utf-8';
  AResponseInfo.ServeFile(AContext, AFileName);
end;
```

Either way, `utf-8` is not a valid value for the HTTP `Content-Encoding` header.  Indy does not assign any value to that header by default, so you must be assigning it manually.  Don't do that in this case.

Comment: Both of your suggestions worked perfectly. Thanks.